# AmCharts zoom out event

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am using AmCharts and have planned very specific operations that should be performed on zoom in and zoom out.

Zoom-in is detected by the "zoomed" event. However, I can't find anything specific for detecting zoom-out. Is it the same event or no even at all ?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution?

Comment: My colleague made it work by `var initEventHandler = function (event) { event.chart.zoomOut = function () { <stuff-we-want-to-do> }; };`. I'm not sure exactly how that works, so I'm not adding this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This detects both zoom-in and zoom-out:

`chart.chartContainer.events.on("wheel", yourFunction);`